# Can't pass multiple arguments to SQL statement into wildcard

Tags: java, sql

I have this fragment of code

```
 final List<Account> result = this.jdbcTemplate.query(LIST_OF_ACCOUNT_SQL, new String[]{ids},
```

When I pass only one argument like

```
        final String ids= "3213";
```

Code is working fine.

But I have problem passing multiple arguments to my wildcard

```
final String ids= "3213, 2313";
```

This is my SQL

```
"SELECT ID, NAME FROM ACCOUNT WHERE STATUS = 'OK' AND ID IN (?) ";
```

I am using Oracle Database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following way

```
String inSql = String.join(",", Collections.nCopies(ids.size(), "?"));
 


List<Account> result = jdbcTemplate.query(
      String.format("SELECT ID, NAME FROM ACCOUNT WHERE STATUS = 'OK' AND ID IN  (%s)", inSql), 
      ids.toArray(), 
      (rs, rowNum) -> new Account(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("NAME")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and `MapSqlParameterSource` which takes care of the array data:

```java
static String LIST_OF_ACCOUNT_SQL = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM Accounts WHERE STATUS = 'OK' AND ID IN (:ids)";

private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

public static List<Account> getAccountsByIds(String[] ids) {
    SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("ids", ids);

    return this.namedJdbcTemplate.query(
            LIST_OF_ACCOUNT_SQL, 
            parameters,
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Account(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("NAME"))
    );
}
```